# WordPress: Ajax post request not getting value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Have an email input that I'm trying to send to a function using Ajax. I retrieve a success message indicating that it's sent however I don't receive a message back from the php function echoing out the value. Can't see where I'm going wrong.

Any help would be great!

Jquery code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var vipEmail = $("#email").val();
        var ajaxurl  = '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php", "relative" ); ?>';

        console.log(vipEmail);

        // This does the ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'add_member',
                member : email
            },
            success:function(data) {
                // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                $(".w-form-done").show();
                $(".sign-up-form").css("display", "none");
            },
            error:function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
                //Show Error Message
                $(".w-form-fail").show();
            }
        });  

    });          

});
```

PHP Code inside functions.php is:

```
function add_member()
{
$member = sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] );
echo $member;  
die();  
}

add_action('wp_ajax_add_member', 'add_member');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_member', 'add_member');
```

Answer (score 2):

You declare a variable `vipEmail`, but you send `member : email`, `email` is not defined.
Then you look for `$_POST['email']` instead of `$_POST['member']`.

So basically change `member : email` to `email : vipEmail`.

Comment: Tried the above and I still get no response back from the php function.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Musa posted, to me it also looks like in `success:function(data)` you're not doing anything with `data`.